# Why the OS allocates more memory than deemed necessary for a small sized executable?

Tags: c++, c, memory, memory-management

Ok so I wrote this minimal C code and complied it to an executable in release mode

```
1.void main()
2.{ for(;;); } //this is here to make the app hang.
```

The executable file size itself is 6kb, I didn't include any headers. Even if the entire exe file gets copied to the ram, apparently it shouldn't occupy more than 7 kb, nevertheless the OS allocates 320 kb, why is that? I'm using windows.

Comment: Depends. What OS? Most likely, it is loading a lot of other libraries, etc. In assembly you could look at this like: `jmp .` or something similar which would be a whole 2 bytes or something depending on your architecture. But it is likely there are system libraries being loaded, stacks being setup, etc. You can disassemble the binary to see exactly what is going on.

Comment: __int__ main()...

Comment: why the "Gestapo" downvotes?? This is a perfectly legitimate question and doesn't deserve to be closed. The only problem is with the question title which should be something like: "Why the OS allocates more memory than deemed necessary for an executable"

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you're confused and mixing a wide variety of concepts. Let me try to explain:

- That program is very clearly an infinite loop which explains why it doesn't end (or what you call "hang").
- The compiler/linker still need to write a valid executable for your OS, and this involves a bunch of headers and stuff, which could be easily consuming 6kb.
- 320kb in a mainstream OS at this point in time seems like almost nothing and it can mainly be OS overhead. It is hard to say more without knowing what OS.

I strongly encourage you to disassemble your code. Another option is to play with your compiler options to optimize for executable size. I think the bottom line is that you're expecting that since your program doesn't do anything useful its size should be zero, and this is an unreasonable expectation.